# Finding current Query-ed field Siebel

Tags: oracle, crm, siebel

I'd like to know if it's possible to retrieve the field that a user is querying on the applet ? Let's say on Contact List Applet, user queries the Name field. So, how can I retrieve the field that's being queried on ?

Hope everyone can share their thoughts on this. Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get that in BusComp's PreQuery event handler as follows:

```js
function BusComp_PreQuery()
{
  var currentSearchExpr:chars = "";
  
  if(TheApplication().ActiveViewName() == "YOUR_VIEW_NAME")
  {
    currentSearchExpr = this.GetSearchExpr();
    // currentSearchExpr = "[Name] = 'ABC'"
  }
}
```